# Enable grow of cross tab in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting, word-wrap, crosstab

I am using a Cross-Tab object in crystal report.  I am having problem making my data column (Field Row) to increase dynamically in height when my data size increases.  Since the "Can Grow" property in the Format Editor is disabled, it would not let me set the "Can Grow" to true to enable this function.  How do I enable the "Can Grow" function so I can set it to true?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem where my row labels did not wrap.

Sadly, I think the best solution is to increase the height of your "data" row field (probably the bottom row).  This does fix the height for ALL rows but it means that text in ALL rows will be able to wrap at the same height.

I was going to post an image but I don't have the rep.

Answer (score -1):

Cross-Tabs, like Charts, are *always* able to grow. For this reason, the "Can Grow"-related formatting options are disabled. It really wouldn't make sense if they couldn't grow since they are dynamic objects.

If you're not seeing some data/rows you would expect, it is because the data is not there or something related to the data source for the Cross-Tab is configured incorrectly.

Comment: I don't experience this behaviour - my rows do not resize and it truncates the text vertically - CanGrow is disabled.

Comment: @Rodney I misread the original question... sounds like you and OP are looking to have the cross-tab work similarly to how Excel will wrap cells. I came across quite a few threads elsewhere with the same question and no real solution. CR2008 doesn't appear to even let you set the field widths via formula in a cross-tab. You may be able to dynamically set field sizes (by counting characters, I suppose) via SDK, but I'm not very familiar with that.